# How to make my react app server side rendering on APACHE SERVER without NodeJS?

Tags: reactjs, apache, xampp, server-side-rendering

I'm running my **`react`** app on **`apache`** server, and it is **`client side rendering`**. I add react to my website using CDN links

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js" integrity="sha256-FiZMk1zgTeujzf/+vomWZGZ9r00+xnGvOgXoj0Jo1jA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Now, I want to shift it to be **`server side rendering`** without using **`Nodejs`**.

What is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, at least not without a vast amount of work.

To get server-side rendering you need to execute the JavaScript on the server. Node.js is the premier out-of-browser JavaScript runtime and all the tools designed to enable server-side rendering for React.js (like Next.js) are designed to work with Node.js.

To get server-side rendering with Apache HTTPD and without Node.js you would need to:

1. Select a JS runtime
2. Implement something akin to Next.js using that runtime
3. Configure Apache HTTP to communicate with that runtime (possibly involving the writing of a whole new Apache module)